# How can I add Failure Actions within service exe?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, atl

How can I program *Failure Actions* in a *Windows Service (using ATL)*, so after I register the service with a call `myservice.exe /service`, Failure Actions are set already?

Answer (score 0):

In your module class, inherited from `CAtlServiceModuleT`, you can override [`Install`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/71wh6b8c%28v=vs.100%29) method and it is a good place to put your code to setup failure actions to:

```
BOOL Install() throw()
{
  if(!__super::Install())
    return FALSE;
  // TODO: Setup Failure Actions
  return TRUE;
}
```

Setting up actions would involve interaction with SCM and you can look base method implementation on hints how you can do it. You might also prefer to override this completely without going to `__super` if you don't want to open SCM handles twice.

Comment: More specifically, use the [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) function to configure the desired failure actions.